# Unsure how this piece of code is doing what it does... .getDescribe()

Tags: apex

I'm relatively new to Apex and Java.

Could someone possibly explain this snippet of code?

```
Map<String, SObjectField> m = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String name : m.keySet()) {
    DescribeFieldResult r = m.get(name).getDescribe();
    System.debug(r);
}
```

I know it's getting the Describe information for each field on the Opportunity object, but could someone explain, line by line, how it's doing it?

Cheers!

Comment: your understanding is correct. Why don't you read manual and explore it?

Comment: I find that sometimes an explanation from an experienced developer can be much more insightful than the documentation.

Comment: i agree it adds value **sometimes** but in this case it wont as the code is very straight forwards and you know what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is straight forward and pretty readable but here it is with some comments.

```
Map<String, SObjectField> m = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap(); 
// Get all fields for the Opportunity object 

for (String name : m.keySet()) { // For each field on Opportunity
    DescribeFieldResult r = m.get(name).getDescribe(); // Describe the current field 
    System.debug(r); // Print the information to the log 
}
```

For more information see:

- [SObjectField](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm)
- [DescribeFieldResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

Comment: Cheers BarCotter, that's all I was looking for!